# How to so send some sensor value from ATmega8a to a Raspberry pi 3 by Serial Communication USART

Tags: raspberry-pi3, microcontroller, serial-communication

I've taken sensor value with ATmega8a.Now I want to send the values from ATmega8a to Raspberry pi using serial communication.Then I want to send my data to firebase server.I'm facing some trouble doing these?Can I get the complete process how I can complete the task?
I've tried with this way.I've sent a string through Tx pin of ATmega8a with 2400 baud rate.

Raspberry pi code:

```
import datetime
from firebase import firebase

import serial
from time import sleep

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://abcd1234******',None)


ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",2400)

while True:
        rdata = ser.read()
        sleep(0.03)
        datal = ser.inWaiting()
        rdata += ser.read(datal)
        str(rdata)
        firebase.post('RUET/KSR',rdata)
```

But the result is...

> 'utf8'code can not decode byte 0xf8 in position 505: invailed start byte.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from trying to convert this data to a string.

```
 str(rdata)
```

If this data contains values that are not valid UTF8, it will fail. You need to encode this data in a way that it can be sent to your database. Can it accept binary data (blobs) ? If so, you should send your data as-is, without converting it to a string.

Strings contain text only, so trying to decode raw binary as if it were strings will usually lead to errors.